# http.post problem after Flutter 2 upgrade

Tags: flutter, http

I have just updated to Flutter 2. I updated all the dependencies including http. Now I have a problem with the following:

```
Future<UserLogin> fetchStaff(String pUserName, String pPassword) async {
  final response = await http
      .post(Uri.encodeFull('$kBaseUrl/LoginService/CheckLogin'),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
          body: '{ "pUser": "$pUserName", "pPassword": "$pPassword"}')
      .timeout(Duration(seconds: kTimeOutDuration));
```

I'm getting an error on the: Uri.encodeFull('$kBaseUrl/LoginService/CheckLogin'

"The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'."

$kBaseUrl = 'https://subdom.mydomain.com:443/mobile';

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post method used to take string previously, now they have modified to Uri

so used, `Uri.parse` to get the `uri`

```
.post(Uri.parse(Uri.encodeFull('$kBaseUrl/LoginService/CheckLogin'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, this is because [`post`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html) function expects a `Uri` and you have passed a `String` (returned by [`Uri.encodeFull`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/encodeFull.html)) to it. You need to use [`Uri.parse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/parse.html) to pass a `Uri` to it.

```
final response = await http
      .post(Uri.parse('$kBaseUrl/LoginService/CheckLogin'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a String, such as:

```
String strUri="${yourBaseUrl}/yourPath/yourFile";
```

Using

```
http.post(Uri.parse(strUri),
  headers: {...},
  body: {...},
);
```

is enough to get all working back.

You may try `Uri.tryParse(strUri)` to handle `null` if the *uri* string is not valid as a URI or URI reference.